# Prototype AJAX Post Parameters missing randomly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, prototype

Alright, so i have a .NET application that uses the Prototype library to make AJAX calls to webmethods in the page-behind to retrieve data.  This application  has been up and running for quite awhile with no issues.  Recently a new user began using the application and experiencing some weird issues.

Basically, what happens is he can use the application fine for awhile and then it just starts throwing errors on AJAX calls stating parameters are missing to the webmethod.  Here is the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException - Unable to perform the requested action:  Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'fleet'.
   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary'2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary'2 parameters)
   AT SYSTEM.WEB.SCRIPT.SERVICES.RESTHANDLER.INVOKEMETHOD(HTTPCONTEXT CONTEXT, WEBSERVICEMETHODDATA METHODDATA, IDICTIONARY`2 RAWPARAMS)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)
```

It isn't just one call that messes up but any ajax call randomnly and it always seems to be the first parameter in the webmethod that is called "missing."  leading me to believe the post data isn't gettin back somehow?  (related?:  [JQuery Ajax post parameters sometimes not sent on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941898/jquery-ajax-post-parameters-sometimes-not-sent-on-ie)).

I have never been able to recreate this issue, nor has any other user experienced it.  This leads me to believe it is something specific on this users system that is causing the issue.  Unfortunately they are a rather important user so i need to attempt to solve this problem.  The user has IE8 as their browser.  Here is the code that makes the ajax call using prototype:

```
function gAjax(url, params, onSuccess, onError, onException, onComplete) {

    new Ajax.Request(url,
    {
         method:'post',                                     //Post
         contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",     //As JSON
         postBody:Object.toJSON(params),                    //Post Body is JSON string
         sanitizeJSON:true,                                 //Sanitize the JSON
         onComplete:onComplete,                             //Set user on complete
         onSuccess:onSuccess,                               //Set user on success
         onFailure:onError,                                 //Set user on error
         onException:onException                            //Set user on exception
    });
}
```

onComplete, onSuccess, onError, onException are function callbacks.  params is an object like the following:

{'fleet':'fleetVal','bin':1234}

Url is the method, such as Bin.aspx/LoadBinInfo.  This method is defined in the backend as follows:

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function LoadBinInfo(ByVal fleet As String, ByVal bin As Integer) As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

        '.....
        'Returns a dictionary of info
    End Function
```

If anyone has any ideas as to what is happening i would greatly appreciate any input!  I can't seem to find any information in my research to lead me to the possible cause.  Again it seems to only happen to this one user, so maybe its a browser setting on his end (any ideas what setting?).  But then again its sporadic for him even, but once it starts happening it happens constantly until he closes out the browser and starts over.

Comment: Sounds like a possible memory leak. Have the user open Task Manager and monitor available FREE RAM over time.

Comment: This application is housed on our server and used by users at many sites.  This issue is only experienced by one user at one site.  The other sites all run with no issues.  A memory leak within the app would cause issues for all users right?  Or are you saying that there is in IE memory leak on their client machine dealing with the JS?

Comment: I have found another lead that might help narrow this down.  The user that is having this issue ALSO sometimes gets an issue on the return.  Sometimes when the AJAX call returns the responseJSON value of the return is null.  could this be interrelated?  And even more i have found that another user at the SAME SITE experiences the NULL responseJSON issue occasionally; although he does NOT ever receive the missing parameter error.  All the evidence seems to point to some issue specific to that site (browser settings, etc.).  Also note that their IT controls their system settings.

Comment: Do you have any handlers running for compression by chance?

Comment: Nope, not that im aware of. The original issue seems to have stopped occuring.... i had the user that was experiencing the problem add the site as trusted and changed the prototype ajax params a little, however the two users are still experience the NULL responseJSON error. I added additional logging to see what response they actually were getting and the response just seems to be blank.  I cannot seem to figure out why this would occur.  It happens randomnly on different calls to webmethods and is no specific to any set.  I will post the transport in the next comment.

Comment: call info
{'request':{'options':{'method':'post','asynchronous':true,'contentType':'application/json','encoding':'UTF-8','parameters':'','evalJSON':'force','evalJS':true,'postBody':'{"crumbId":1}','global':true},'transport':{'status':200,'responseXML':,'readyState':4,'responseText':'','statusText':'Unknown'},'url':'/Default.aspx/GetCrumbLink','method':'post','parameters':{},'body':'{"crumbId":1}','_complete':true},'transport':{'status':200,'responseXML':,'readyState':4,'responseText':'','statusText':'Unknown'},'readyState':4,'status':200,'statusText':'Unknown','responseText':'','responseXML':}

Comment: Maybe this is a separate issue and i should start a new thread, but seeing as it experienced by the same two users still and is kind of the same thing just i on the response i feel they are related.  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering here because it seems I don't have enough reputation as to comment rather than answering.
It's not very clear what is missing from the request, but I'd go on checking the web logs (or setting some sort of logging) to see what the system is actually receiving. According to your description of the problem, the request is somehow missing the 'fleet' parameter. But you are not sending such value isolated in the request, you're sending all data in the post body as a serialized JSON string.
So, either the data passed to gAjax is not correct/complete, or something strange is happening on your server.
I obviously suspect that it's the former, but anyway you should try to log and debug on both ends.
For a start, I'd do something like this:

```
function gAjax(url, params, onSuccess, onError, onException, onComplete) {

    params['debug']=Object.toJSON(params);
    new Ajax.Request(url,
//....
```

That will add the JSON string to the request so you can check exactly what is being sent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So the issue with the parameters not making it to the backend has been corrected, this i think was an issue on there end with their browser.  The facility these two users are working from is highly regulated.  I assume the issue is some setting on their end since they are the only 2 this happens to.  The only remaining issue is that a response never makes it back.  So lets say they make a call to update an entry, the call is made the entry is updated, and the results are returned.  All this works except the users never get the results back!  I added logging to write what they receive (next)

Comment: Here is the response they receive (comment 1 of 2):
{'request':{'options':{'method':'post','asynchronous':true,'contentType':'application/json','encoding':'UTF-8','parameters':'','evalJSON':'force','evalJS':true,'postBody':'{"crumbId":2}','global':true},'transport':{'status':200,'timeout':0,'responseXML':,'readyState':4,'responseText':'','statusText':'Unknown'},'url':'/Critical_Spares/Default.aspx/GetCrumbLink','method':'post','parameters':{},'body':'{"crumbId":2}','_complete':true},'transport':

Comment: {'status':200,'timeout':0,'responseXML':,'readyState':4,'responseText':'','statusText':'Unknown'},'readyState':4,'status':200,'statusText':'Unknown','responseText':'','responseXML':}

so as you can see the status is 200 for successful but the response objects are all empty and the response text is Unknown!  The call was successful though and results were returned from the server they just don't get received by the user : /.