# ie 10 ajax post with params not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, internet-explorer-10

we are developing a html5/jquery application for data manipulation; this application includes both http get and http post operations. With ie version < 10, ff, and chrome, our save/delete/update operations works flawlessly (the post sends the object's information as xml to the server for validation) but in our ie 10 browser running on windows 8, it seems like the ajax post operation does not allow data parameters ie. doesnt send the ajax data.

similar posts have suggested to use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >
```

and other variations, but this does not work.

The problem seems to be as soon as we add the following:

```
data: {
            'lngClassID': 0,
            'strAttributes': xmlAsAString,
            'strExtendedPar': ""
        },
```

it does not go through, even if the data has 1 param. Some forums have suggested it's an internal IE10 known issue but i find it hard to believe that this is the case... this means anyone using IE10 cannot make any post requests on any page on the internet? highly unlikely...

If i compare the data from the 'Network' tab in the developer menu, it shows that the request headers are 100% identical, and all other information is identical

from ie 10 and 9 browsers:
[image]

I have also read that this issue was raised with the jquery team and was closed with 'CantFix' tag...

anyone have any solutions? ideas? this one really has us stumped...

**EDIT:**
The ajax request is as follows:

```
DeleteBusinessObject: function (strAttributes, strExtendedPar, fncCallback) {
    var webServiceUrl = ServiceAccess.GetRootURL() + "/DeleteBusinessObject";
    var promise = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webServiceUrl,
        dataType: "xml",
        context: this,
        data: {                
            'strAttributes': strAttributes,
            'strExtendedPar': strExtendedPar
        },
        error: this.ManageServerException
    });
    promise.done(fncCallback);
},
```

where strAttributes is a really long string which contains all the xml data with the '<' and '/>' tags converted to ASCII. POST requests are not supposed to have a max-length associated to them so i doubt that's the problem.  The weird part is that any request using GET works without any problems so im lead to believe iits really an IE 10 issue with POST requests with any data params?

**EDIT2:**

I confirm the browser is not running compatibility mode
[image]

**EDIT 3:**
I have found a solution to this problem. As it turns out, the web service protocol HttpPost was not in the list of protocols in the web.config file. simply adding the line

```
<add name="HttpPost" />
```

within WebServices > Protocols was all i needed to do. I'm still not sure as to why it would work on ie9, ff and chrome but not on safari and ie10

Comment: Can you show how you're making the post request?

Comment: Can you show us the ajax request code?

Comment: You might also want to look at fiddler to see what that says.

Comment: @ColinDeClue:  I found a fiddle which fires an ajax request http://jsfiddle.net/L6bJ2/297/

it works with no data params but the minute i introduce a data param like: str:'hello', nothing happens with i fire the ajax request

Comment: @AzurGroup: That fiddle works fine for me in IE10.

Comment: ?? really ?? i dont get it. There has to be an explanation for this! there must be something in my settings which is causing this not to work properly...

Comment: Can you confirm that IE10 is displaying the page in standards mode, and not compatibility mode?

Comment: i confirm - please see EDIT2
i'm continuously reading on this issue and the suggested problem relates to cross-domain issues - but we are running the web services and hosting the website locally so i'm not 100% sure if this is the root problem

Comment: I've allowed cross-domain requests in my browsers options and it's still not working therefore i can rule out that its a cross-domain issue :(

Comment: I'm preety sure this is what you need [view this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941898/jquery-ajax-post-parameters-sometimes-not-sent-on-ie)