# Unable to get Post data

Tags: c#, jquery

JS code:

```
function save( ref, text){
            $.post("save.aspx", {cc:"us", ref:ref, text:text}, function(data){
                $("[data-ref='"+ref+"'] .loader").animate({opacity:0},500,function(){
                    $(this).parent().removeClass("saving");
                    $(this).remove();
                });

            });
        }
```

CS file Code:

```
public partial class save : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // $_REQUEST['cc'];
       // HttpContext.Current.Response
        string strcc = Request.Form["cc"];
        string strRef = Request.Form["ref"];
        string strtext =Request.Form["text"];
    }
}
```

Unable to get the values passed from JS code to next page, what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you put your post parameters in between quote like : `{"cc":"us", "ref":ref, "text":text}`

Comment: @ashish i don't think it matters if you put quote or not.

Comment: @Ashish I tried that too but it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I'm almost sure that ASPX page code executes before JS function calls it. You may trace this with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Checked with fiddler, In IE i Find this 
POST http://localhost:41162/Admin/save.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:41162/Admin/translate.aspx?cc=af
Accept-Language: en-IN
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; MDDSJS)
Host: localhost:41162
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

Comment: and in Chrome
POST http://localhost:41162/Admin/save.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:41162
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 49
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:41162
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:41162/Admin/translate.aspx?cc=af
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

cc=us&ref=msg_share_title&text=Sharing+is+caringr

Comment: Chrome able to get the data but not in IE any reason?

Comment: Which page is calling localhost:41162/Admin/save.aspx? Do you have that JS script on another page or also on save.aspx?

Comment: That script is in different page /admin/translate.aspx

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure, it's hitting Save.aspx page

Comment: Which IE version do you use? It seems that this is some bug in IE regarding this ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941898/jquery-ajax-post-parameters-sometimes-not-sent-on-ie ). I tested this on IE11 and it works fine.

Comment: I'm using IE 10 on win 7

Comment: Sad but this is a bug in IE10 http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/771016 . You may try to run in compatibility mode but this is just a workaround.