# internet explorer 11 doesn't resolve POST variables through AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I noticed that my `POST` request using AJAX on IE simply fails. What I mean by fails is that it throws an error that the key wasn't found:  `$_POST['myKey']`. However, the same code works fine in Opera, Chrome and Firefox. For some reason, IE just doesn't send the POST variables.

A quick test resulted that if I use the `GET` request using AJAX it works just as expected. Why IE won't resolve the `POST` variables?

Works:

```
$.get('ajax/changeDayTimesDisplay.php', {display: display, id: id});
```

Doesn't work:

```
$.post('ajax/changeDayTimesDisplay.php', {display: display, id: id});
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6941898/3310441

Comment: @KoenW Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be a duplicate since in his question sometimes it actually works but in my case it NEVER works. I didn't encounter one time where it actually received my post request variables

Comment: You could troubleshoot this at the PHP end by logging the $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] and "file_get_contents('php://input')".  Then check the difference between ie and any other browser.