# Angular 2 - IE 11 issue with http get request

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angular

I have a very weird problem with my angular app in IE11. This is what happens:

On a 3 page (3 different routes) website one is not working on first load (it works if I press F5 and/or I have opened the web dev console). That page I have debugged because it loads half of it. It breaks when it reaches this part of the code in the component:

```
...

constructor(public http: Http) {

    //... stuff

    http.get('./data/data.json')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => { 
            alert ('test');

        },
       // err => console.error(err)//,
       // () => console.log('done')
    );

    //... stuff
}
```

The alert won't show up on first load but it will if I reload or if the console is open. No other js errors show up, other browsers do perfectly fine from the get go.

What I have:

I have angular version 2.0.0-rc.4 and am using this shim: https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js

What I've tried so far:

I've tried lots of different shims, some broke my web, none did anything so I came back to what I initially had (my web is based upon the heroes tutorial, worked from there).

I've tried changing angular version but it breaks the website that is finished and I cannot afford to upgrade all my code to a new version. I can't break the website at this moment to fix one issue with IE.

I've added this to the index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

No change with that. I also tried removing the cache with metas, no changes either.

Anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Use an observable .retry().

Answer (score 0):

a few days ago, I had a same problem. it is a really crazy bug of IE.

In my case, the reason of this problem is that IE can't recognize doctype html for html5 with specific conditions. (not all time, but sometimes)

```
<!doctype html>
```

when IE can't recognize this doctype-html declaration, IE browser enters quirks mode and tries to deal with code as if it was written in the late 90's. that's the main reason of why IE uses Internet Explore 5 mode.

[What happens when you remove doctype from the HTML page](https://medium.com/@heitorhherzog/what-happens-when-you-remove-doctype-from-the-html-page-b062e6a0beec#:%7E:text=Without%20a%20Doctype%3A&text=The%20purpose%20of%20DOCTYPE%20is,HTML%20as%20best%20it%20can.)

and, sadly, IE 5 mode has critical problem, it can't use ajax request/response correctly. sometimes, it can call, but other times, it can't call.

[jquery-ajax-post-parameters-sometimes-not-sent-on-ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941898/jquery-ajax-post-parameters-sometimes-not-sent-on-ie)
[how-to-detect-server-or-networking-failures-when-using-xmlhttp](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2826958/how-to-detect-server-or-networking-failures-when-using-xmlhttp)

So, the solution of this problem is using strict-declaration of html4 instead of using html5 declaration to prevent IE enters into quirks mode. IE 11 can't support Html5 perfectly. you can search and find a lot of problem cases of IE 11 with html5.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

[Document Type Definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html)